# Call ajax on browser close, not url change

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I want to insert logout time stamp when user does not manually logout from application i.e., if user closes browser without logging out from the system, the system should log out on browser close event or any other solution to do the same using jquery, ajax, and php is welcomed. I tried following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      window.onbeforeunload = function() {
          $.ajax
            ({ 
                url: 'logout.php',
                data: "",
                type: 'post',
                success: function()
                {
                    .....
                }
            });
      }
</script>
```

But  window.onbeforeunload  function()  is logging me out everytime the url changes in webkit browsers like chrome, as it's characteristics. I need some cross browser solution. I saw various que-ans on stackoverflow itself regarding this issue but i couldn't find any solution which helped me in my case.

*And i also need to mention that in logout.php i use the code for session termination and insert query in database as well for logged-out timestamp.*

Comment: Thats because every page in your site gets unloaded as the user moves to the next page!!! DUH!

Comment: I may be getting it wrong and please correct me if I do, but how one is supposed to see anything that's been displayed in a browser scope if there is no browser left since it was closed?

Comment: I dont know. You may be right, But there must be some way so that if anyhow user do not log out manually, and we need some code, in my case code written in logout.php , to run so that database don't have an logout date value. @AlanMachado

Comment: That is understandable sir! @RiggsFolly. But if you suggest some solution that fits in my case will be appreciated.

Comment: You cannot tell when a user just goes away without logging out. All you can tell is that they have been inactive for a period of time. And that means when they go to each page in your site you have to update a `last_active` timestamp. If `now - last_active > session timeout period` you can assume they have gone away. Afterall the session will no longer be valid after that period anyway, so they would be forced to login again anyway at that point.

Comment: The case is as @AlanMachado has asked in comment section. If there is no browser left, how would i run some sort of js code or any other code. so i have to do something on browser close event and which is not cross- browser compatible. Is there anything in php that fires just before session destroyed automatically or any interruption occurrence detection method like on machine shutdown, or browser close, session time out, and we can add some code to that function? i am very enthusiast to use if there is provision for such things in php.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest following code for ajax call on browser close.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onbeforeunload = function() {

        var ticketId = $('#ticketId').val();
        $.ajax({
            url: '/ticket-window-close/'+ticketId,
            type: 'GET',
            async: false,
            timeout: 10000
        });
    };
</script>
```